# mvc5 bootstrap updated now menu bar is not working fine

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

After updating mvc5 via package manage now menu is not working fine,

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("ABC High School", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

while opening menus on corner and style is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include popper.js after jquery
- then change the classes on your navbar to arrange more like the bootstrap templates on the docs 
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

There are problems if you have custom css in bundles on page level but check for element level css in your css files particular to the page

good luck